# Installing php-mysql on centos 6.5 fails due to conflicts when percona client 5.5 also installed

Tags: mysql, php, centos6, percona, percona-xtradb-cluster

Some background: I'm writing a Chef cookbook to set up a LNMP stack for local development. It requires the `php-mysql` library for PHP 5.4 (using the `php` package). We're using the `yum-remi` repository for installing these.

For local development of our web application, we require Percona server installed (5.5) in addition to the client (this issue doesn't seem to exist with 5.6). For testing the recipe responsible just for installing PHP and its modules, we only require the libmysqlclient.so.16, which we get through Percona client. Right now I'm focusing on just getting the PHP recipe to work, but a solution that works when server is installed would be ideal. These get installed from the repo at http://repo.percona.com/centos/6/os/x86_64/ using the [Chef-Percona cookbook](https://github.com/phlipper/chef-percona)

The packages that get installed are:

```
install version 5.5.42-rel37.1.el6 of package Percona-Server-devel-55
install version 5.5.42-rel37.1.el6 of package Percona-Server-client-55
```

The PHP-mysql is:

```
yum -d0 -e0 -y install php-mysql-5.4.40-1.el6.remi
```

That always throws this error:

```
STDOUT:  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
        You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest       
STDERR: Error: Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-shared-55 conflicts with Percona-Server-shared-55-5.5.42-rel37.1.el6.x86_64
```

Essentially `Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-shared-55` is a dependency of `php-mysql`.

If I don't install anything Percona first, I get this error:

```
STDOUT: ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) is needed by postfix-2:2.6.6-6.el6_5.x86_64
libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) is needed by postfix-2:2.6.6-6.el6_5.x86_64
  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

If I only include the `percona::package_repo` (which simply adds the Percona repository to the `yum repolist`) and don't install the client, it actually does install `php-mysql`, however with the following versions:

```
yum list installed | grep Percona
Percona-Server-shared-51.x86_64
Percona-Server-shared-56.x86_64
Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-shared-55.x86_64
```

As I mentioned before, this might be ok in an isolated environment, but another recipe in my LNMP cookbook will be installing Percona server 5.5 on the same environment, and I'm anticipating conflicts with the above if that is the case. I tested this out and it was the case - I got the same `Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-shared-55 conflicts with Percona-Server-shared-55-5.5.42-rel37.1.el6.x86_64` error as before.

I've tried a number of possible solutions, including installing `Percona-Server-shared-compat` but it always seems to conflict. Any ideas on what I can do to fix it?

Comment: No, that seems fine. You generally shouldn't install the Percona _dependencies_ explicitly, but let your other packages specify what they need.

Comment: Which part seems fine?

Comment: The part where you "don't install anything Percona first".

Comment: Is there a better repository to get `libmysqlclient.so.16`?

Comment: If you're using Percona you get it from them. If you're using MariaDB you get it from them. And so on...

Comment: Right, which is why I haven't looked elsewhere. Should I be looking at using previous versions of the yum packages? Where can I find older version #s?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: To avoid these version conflicts so, you know, it works as expected. Do you have another solution?

Comment: Only what I've already said!